# How to connect 3 List view webparts in Sharepoint?

Tags: list, web-part, connected-web-parts

I have 3 SharePoint lists A,B,C.
I have inserted the lists in a SharePoint page.

B and C lists have a column which is lookup to the column of list A.

So now I want when I select a item from list A,its associated items from B and C list should appear.

How it should be done?
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the page you can select 'connections' from the webpart 'context' menu. Use this to connect web parts to the 'master' webpart (in your case list view A) or a filter web part

More info here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYU8bQ6Sw8I

http://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/

Comment: I did the mentioned steps.But Only list B is getting filtered.List C is not getting filtered.

Comment: You should be able to connect multiple 'consumers' to one filter.

Comment: List C is a task list and List A is a Calendar,List B is a document library.The connections is happening but the task list is not getting filtered.Document Library is getting filtered though.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the both the connections?